# Grabbing a screenshot programmatically in webos

Tags: webos

Is there any way to grab a screenshot of the currently active screen in webos programmatically?

The use-case is an app that takes a screen shot every few seconds for recording user activity.

**EDIT:** I'm interested in code that actually runs on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a private service bus API to grab a screenshot that you can use from the shell via luna-send:

```
luna-send -n 1 luna://com.palm.systemmanager/takeScreenShot '{"file":"sshot.png"}'
```

This won't work from a non-com.palm application, so it's possible to do this in homebrew, but not in a catalog app.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I was actually interested in code that grabs the frame buffer on board the device. Thanks for your tip though!

Comment: The luna-send command is just showing the service invocation.  If you're app was run with an com.palm.* name, it would use that via a Mojo or Enyo service call.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was being silly. Accepted answer for you mate.