# How to take a picture using command line on webOS on HP touchpad?

Tags: webos, touchpad

on webos, I have openssh running and would like to take a picture using the command line script.

I suspect this is going to include some luna-send command, or alternatively a gst-launch

But I am not having any luck with the docs.

webos doesn't have any of the expected capture tools, but I can access the /dev/video0 device.

Edit: i noticed that the touchpad has the ffmpeg utility installed, but it doesn't recognise the video4linux2 format

So far, I am trying Gopherkhan's suggestions with the following code;

```
luna-send -n 1 palm://com.palm.mediad.MediaCapture/startImageCapture \
'{"path":"/media/internal/foo1.png","options":[{"quality" \
:100,"flash":2,'reviewDuration':0,'exifData':{}}]}'
```

but its just hanging there doing nothing, after a while is says this;

```
{"serviceName":"com.palm.mediad.MediaCapture","returnValue":false,"errorCode":-1 \
  ,"errorText":"com.palm.mediad.MediaCapture is not running."} \
(process:8534): LunaService-CRITICAL **: AppId msg type: 17
```

Comment: This is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419662/grabbing-a-screenshot-programmatically-in-webos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to do this with luna-sends is a bit tricky, and technically not supported.

You're probably going to want to hit the MediaCapture library, which can be found on the device here:

```
/usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/0.10/framework/lib/mediacapture
```

To include it in your enyo app drop the following in your depends.js:

```
"$enyo-lib/mediacapture/"
```

There are three main steps involved.

1. Initializing the component
2. Capturing the image
3. Unloading the device.

Here's a sample:

**Declare the component in your scene**

```
{
            kind: "enyo.MediaCapture", name:"mediaCaptureObj", 
            onLoaded:"_setUpLoadedState", onInitialized:"_setUpInitializedState", 
            onImageCaptureStart:"_onImageCaptureStart", onImageCaptureComplete:"_onImageCaptureComplete",
         onAutoFocusComplete:"_onAutoFocusComplete", onError:"_handleError",
            onElapsedTime:"_onElapsedTime", onVuData:"_onVuDataChange", onDuration:"_onDuration"
}
```

**Call the initialize method**:

```
this.$.mediaCaptureObj.initialize(this.$.ViewPort);
```

**In your onInitialized callback**

Use the property bag to locate the number of devices that are available.  Typically, the descriptions are "Camera/Camcorder", "Front Microphone", and "User facing camera"

```
var keyString;
for(var i = 0; i < this.pb.deviceKeys.length; i++)
{
    if(this.pb.deviceKeys[i].description.indexOf("Camera/Camcorder") >= 0)
    {
        keyString = this.pb.deviceKeys[i].deviceUri;
        break;
    }
}

if(keyString)
{
    var formatObj = {
                imageCaptureFormat: this.pb[keyString].supportedImageFormats[0]
            };

    this.$.mediaCaptureObj.load(keyString, formatObj);
}
```

**Take a photo**.

```
var obj = {"exifData":"{\"make\": \"Palm\", \"model\": \"Pre3\", \"datetime\": \"2011:05:19 10:39:18\", \"orientation\": 1, \"geotag\": {}}","quality":90,"flash":"FLASH_ON"};

this.$.mediaCaptureObj.startImageCapture("", obj);
```

**Unload the device**:

```
this.$.mediaCaptureObj.unload();
```

To do this with the old JS frameworks, see:
https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/javascript-libraries/media-capture.html

Now, you can do something similar with luna-send, but again, I don't think it's technically supported. You might have trouble with starting-up/keeping-alive the media capture service, etc. **BUT**, if you want to try, you could do something along the lines of:

**1. get the media server instance** --- this returns a port instance number

```
luna-send -a your.app.id -i palm://com.palm.mediad/service/captureV3 '{"args":["subscribe":true]}'
```

This will return a location of the capture service with a port number, a la:

```
{"returnValue":true, "location":"palm://com.palm.mediad.MediaCaptureV3_7839/"}
```

Since this is a subscription, don't kill the request. Just open a new terminal.

**2. Open a new terminal**. Use the "location" returned in step 1 as your new service uri:

```
luna-send -a your.app.id -i palm://com.palm.mediad.MediaCaptureV3_7839/load '{"args":["video:1", {"videoCaptureFormat":{"bitrate":2000000,"samplerate":44100,"width":640,"height":480,"mimetype":"video/mp4","codecs":"h264,mp4a.40"},"imageCaptureFormat":{"bitrate":0,"samplerate":1700888,"width":640,"height":480,"mimetype":"image/jpeg","codecs":"jpeg"},"deviceUri":"video:1"}]}'
```

You should see:

```
{"returnValue":true}
```

if the call completed correctly. You can safely ctrl+c out of this call.

**3. Take your picture.** (you can ctrl+c out of the last call, and just supply the args here)

```
luna-send -a your.app.id -i palm://com.palm.mediad.MediaCaptureV3_7839/startImageCapture '{"args":["", {"exifData":"{\"orientation\": 1, \"make\": \"HP\", \"model\": \"TouchPad\", \"datetime\": \"2011:09:22 15:34:36\", \"geotag\": {}}","quality":90,"flash":"FLASH_DISABLED","orientation":"faceup"}]}'
```

Again, you should see:

```
{"returnValue":true}
```

if the call completed correctly.

You should hear a shutter click, and the image will show up in the Photos app, in your Photo Roll.

Comment: I tried ;luna-send -n 1 palm://com.palm.mediad.MediaCapture/startImageCapture '{"path":"/media/internal/foo1.png","options":[{"quality" :100,"flash":2,'reviewDuration':0,'exifData':{}}]}'

Comment: thats not working, hangs at the command line with no visible effect on the touchpad

Comment: Updated again. And included better descriptions of the luna-sends. This technically should work. And apparently video capture is coming in about a month or two.

Comment: Ok, thanks! that process works. steps 2 and 3 don't ever return though. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Basically it's because they establish subscriptions. If you did it through the framework, you'd have to kill them all with an unload call. I don't know whether you're looking to do this in production, or just for testing, but you could just cancel calls 2 and 3 after x millis, or just establish all three calls, and cancel after you see the file show up in media/internal. I'll test again this morning just in case.

Comment: So I played around with this this afternoon. All the calls establish subscriptions, so they last until you ctrl-c them. Calls 2 and 3 can be safely cancelled out of after you see the {"returnValue":true} block. As long as you keep call 1 active, you can keep issuing 3 to take more pictures. However, if you reissue 2, with bad parameters, you'll have to set up the whole thing from scratch again.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, which might some benefit of using cross platform tools, is to the use the gst-launch pipeline. So far I have managed to start the web cam using command line;

`gst-launch camsrc .src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 
! palmvideoencoder ! avimux name=mux ! filesink location=test1.avi alsasrc ! 
palmaudioencoder`

but not take a single image;

```
   gst-launch -v camsrc .src_still take-picture=1 flash-ctrl=2 ! fakesink dump=true
```

but I can't get it to recognise the .src_still tab. I will update this answer with this alternative method as I proceed.