# How to take a picture with MediaCapture in Enyo (webOS)?

Tags: javascript, webos, enyo

I'm a kind of newbie webOS Developer, and I'm currently
developing an App where I need to take a picture of 
a certain user.

I've been looking for many resources and sites on the 
internet but I can't find a solution for my problem.

I follow the instructions that list here:

[How to take a picture using command line on webOS on HP touchpad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509675/how-to-take-a-picture-using-command-line-on-webos-on-hp-touchpad)

I want to let clear that I don't want to take the photo from the command line.

I tried the following:

**A. Include in my depends.js**

```
"$enyo/../lib/mediacapture/"
```

**B. In my scene**

```
enyo.kind({
name: "MyComponent",
kind: "Pane",
components: [
    {
        kind: "enyo.MediaCapture",
        name: "mediaCapture",
        onInitialized: "onImageCaptureInitialized",
        onError: "onImageCaptureError",
        onImageCaptureComplete: "onImageCaptureComplete"
    }
],
...
..
.
});
```

**C. Inside the onCreate function**

```
create: function () {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.$.mediaCapture.initialize(this.$.ViewPort);
},
```

**D. Inside the onInitialized Event**

```
onImageCaptureInitialized: function () {
    var keyString;                              
    for(var i = 0; i < this.pb.deviceKeys.length; i++) {
        if(this.pb.deviceKeys[i].description.indexOf("Camera/Camcorder") >= 0) {
              keyString = this.pb.deviceKeys[i].deviceUri;
              break;
        }
    }

    if(keyString) {
        var formatObj = {imageCaptureFormat: this.pb[keyString].supportedImageFormats[0]};
        this.$.mediaCapture.load(keyString, formatObj);
    }
},
```

**D. Inside the onclick Event of a certain button**

```
takePhotoClickEvent: function (inSender) {      

    this.$.mediaCapture.startImageCapture("/media/internal/CanalCocina/recipe_photo.jpg",
        { 
            "bitrate":128000,
            "samplerate":8000,
            "width":480,
            "height":320,
            "mimetype":"image/jpeg",
            "codecs":"jpeg"}
        );  
},
```

When I run the app on the HP TouchPad I get the next log in my console:

> info: MediaCapture::ServiceProxy =====
>   MediaCapture::_initializeMediaServerInstanceSuccess()
>   ...palm://com.palm.mediad.MediaCaptureV3_1814440/,
>   /usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/1.0/framework/lib/mediacapture/helper/MediaCaptureProxyHelper.js:83
>   [20111017-16:52:32.906482] info: MediaCapture::ServiceProxy
>   @@@@@@----------- FIRST PROPERTY GRAB -----------@@@@@@,
>   /usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/1.0/framework/lib/mediacapture/helper/MediaCaptureProxyHelper.js:106
>   [20111017-16:52:32.913991] info: MediaCapture::ServiceProxy
>   inResponse:
>   {"propertyValues":[{"name":"ready","value":false},{"name":"supportedAudioFormats","value":[{"bitrate":128000,"samplerate":8000,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":256000,"samplerate":16000,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":705600,"samplerate":44100,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":128000,"samplerate":8000,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":256000,"samplerate":16000,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":705600,"samplerate":44100,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":128000,"samplerate":8000,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":256000,"samplerate":16000,"width":0,"height":0,"mimetype":"audio/vnd.wave","codecs":"1"},{"bitrate":705600,"sampl

However when the app tries to load the mediaCapture Object I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deviceKeys' of undefined,
>   source/CCRecipesStep1View.js:186

I know and I understand that this error is because the App try to access a property that doesn't exist. In this
case the particular line is:

```
onImageCaptureInitialized: function () {
    var keyString;                              
    for(var i = 0; i < this.pb.deviceKeys.length; i++)    <<------------ Here
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

The file MediaCapture.js and the instructions I follow talk about the **"Property Bag"** , I understand that this is where you declare the properties, however I don't know how
to get the device keys that I need to load the MediaCaptureObject.

When the button is pressed I get:

> MediaCapture::ServiceProxy #######----------- CHANGE PROPERTIES EVENT
>   -----------######vuData      , /usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/1.0/framework/lib/mediacapture/helper/MediaCaptureProxyHelper.js:140
>   [20111017-17:07:35.401836] info: MediaCapture::ServiceProxy
>
> #----------- CHANGE PROPERTIES EVENT -----------######vuData      ,
>
> /usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/1.0/framework/lib/mediacapture/helper/MediaCaptureProxyHelper.js:140
>   [20111017-17:07:35.653586] info: MediaCapture::ServiceProxy
>
> #----------- CHANGE PROPERTIES EVENT -----------######vuData      ,
>
> /usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/1.0/framework/lib/mediacapture/helper/MediaCaptureProxyHelper.js:140
>   [20111017-17:07:35.885940] info: MediaCapture::ServiceProxy
>
> #----------- CHANGE PROPERTIES EVENT -----------######vuData      ,
>
> /usr/palm/frameworks/enyo/1.0/framework/lib/mediacapture/helper/MediaCaptureProxyHelper.js:140

And start an infinite loop :S

I hope you cal help me.
This App is very important.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the samples in the 3.0.4 SDK?

It comes with a MediaCapture sample app that takes pictures. The method to obtain the `deviceUri` is completely different than what you are doing, the initialize method gets the format list as an argument.

Comment: Yes, actually the release was 3 or 4 days ago. In webOS 3.0.2 camera was not available. I'll edit my question early. Thanks.